# Thin linear gradient doesn't display in Firefox for Android

Tags: android, html, css, firefox

I'm creating a menu that has elements underlined with a gradient line. The gradients display fine on desktop and in Chrome for Android, but don't show in Firefox for Android. I used the Firefox WebIDE to debug the error.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="menu">
  <div>Menu1</div>
  <div>Menu2</div>
  <div>Menu3</div>
  <div>Menu4</div>
  <div>Menu5</div>
</div>
```

```
.menu > div {
  position: relative;

  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu > div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -0.05vw;
  left: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  height: 0.05vw;

  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, white 25%, white 75%, transparent);
}
```

On Chrome for Android it's very thin, just as I'd like.

It seems that `0.05vw` is too thin to for FF for Android to display, because from `0.13vw` and up it starts to show, but it's too thick that way. `calc(0.4px + 0.05vw)` shows and it's a little better that way, but still too thick.

If I ditch the gradient in favor of a solid white background, it shows and is thin, so currently I'm using that as fallback, though not ideal.

Phone is a `Galaxy S4` with `FF` for Android `67.0.3`.

Is there a way to make it display, or do I need to solve it in a different way?

Comment: Have you tried adding `.menu > div:after { min-height: 1px }`? Thinner than 1px is not possible anyways, so if you set that, it should always be at least 1px tall

Comment: Phones don't map pixel to pixel, so 1px is pretty thick on them. I completely forgot about min-height, and `min-height: 0.5px` made it a lot better. Still a bit thicker than without it and with the solid color, but this is very usable, thanks!